# How to pass a TComparer<T> class to a generic type in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, generics

I want to create a generic record with some functionality, including a search function. 
To perform this search I wanted to pass a custom Comparer to compare items.
If it were a class, I could pass it in the constructor, but I want to use a record to avoid to create or free it. So, I don't have a constructor where to initialize the Comparer.

Then I decided to pass the Comparer class like a Type parameter, and when I need the comparer, create a instance of the comparer using TComparer.Default.

Well, here is the code:

```
TMyArray<T,C: TComparer<T>> = record
  FComparer: IComparer<T>;
  Items: TArray<T>;

  function Contains<AItem: T>: Boolean;
end;
```

The problem appears when I try to use it in this way:

```
TMyRecord = record
  Score: Real;
  A: string;
  B: string;
end;

TMyRecordComparer = class(TComparer<TMyRecord>)
  function Compare(Left, Right: TMyRecord): Integer;
end;

TMyRecordArray = TMyArray<TMyRecord, TMyRecordComparer>;
```

With this last declaration, I get this error:
E2515 Type parameter 'T' is not compatible with type 'System.Generics.Defaults.TComparer\'.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: You do know that ever since Delphi 2007 which added support for [Advanced records](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Records_.28advanced.29) you can create recorrdswhich have their own constructors that can be used to set custom initial state of the record?

Comment: Yes, I knew Advanced Records. The problem is that you don't have to call a constructor, you can start using your record without call that constructor. This constructor are useful to initialize record fields, that's not the case. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Silver Indeed. The benefit of enhanced records is not that you can add constructors to them.

Comment: Pardon me but I was thinking about using parameterles constructors which would be automatically called as marco has mentioned in [Cusom Managed Records comming in Delphi 10.3](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2018-november-custom-managed-records-delphi.html) but only today I have seen that this feature was defered and pushed back to Delphi 10.4 release [Deferring Delphi Managed Records Support](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2018-november-deferring-managed%20records.html) due to some issues that this feature was causing to RTTI.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While David's answer fixes the problem with the compile error, I would actually use a different constraint:

```
TMyArray<T; C: class, constructor, IComparer<T>> = record
```

That means `C` must be a class with a parameterless constructor and implement the `IComparer<T>` interface. That relaxes the constraint a little, as you don't have to inherit your comparer from `System.Generics.Collections.TComparer<T>` but only implement the needed `IComparer<T>` interface.

Also, fwiw, with the code posted in your question you will get a W1010 warning which means you are missing an override on your `TMyRecordComparer.Compare` method (and its missing `const`). This is needed if you inherit from `TComparer<T>` as that one implements `IComparer<T>` with a virtual abstract method.

Your idea to use `.Default` will also not work as that one creates a default implementation for a comparer for type `T`. But you want to use the custom one you specified.

So with the constraint I wrote above you then can do something like this (naive non-threadsafe implementation):

```
function TMyArray<T, C>.Contains<AItem>: Boolean;
begin
  if FComparer = nil then
    FComparer := C.Create;
  // ....
end;
```

And last but not least, I am not sure your `Contains` method is correct - the way you wrote it suggests that you want to check if your array contains an element of type `AItem` that is of type `T` or a sub type (or if `T` is an interface type, implements `T`) - I would guess you meant to write

```
function Contains(AItem: T): Boolean;
```

Comment: I was passing a comparer class with an overwritten Default that returns an instance of my comparer, so it was working properly, but obviously your solution seems to be a better one.

Thanks!!!

Comment: It would not have worked. `TComparer<T>.Default` is not virtual so even if you also add a `Default` method in your comparer class inside the `TMyArray` code it would not call your `Default` method but the one from `TComparer<T>` as it only sees that one via constraint.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is the syntax of your constraint:

```
TMyArray<T,C: TComparer<T>>
```

This constrains both `T` and `C` to be `TComparer<T>`.

Instead you need this:

```
TMyArray<T; C: TComparer<T>>
```

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Constraints_in_Generics#Specifying_Generics_with_Constraints) gives examples of the various syntax options.